# Docker Compose Error: services Additional property ​* is not allowed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

### Question

- Is the following output an error?

### Target

- I want to run frontend, backend and a database container through Docker.
- I want to hot reload my docker-compose builds on code changes.

### Context

- If I run this on **PowerShell**: `docker-compose build; docker-compose up -d`, I ran into this:

```
services Additional property ​mongodb is not allowed
services Additional property ​mongodb is not allowed
```

**docker-compose.yml:**

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  api:
    build: ./api
    container_name: api
    ports:
      - 4080:4080
    networks:
      - network-backend
      - network-frontend
    depends_on:
      - '​mongodb'
    volumes:
      - .:/code
      
  ​mongodb:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - network-backend
    volumes:
      - db-data:/mongo-data

volumes:
  db-data:

networks:
  network-backend:
  network-frontend:
```

I thought this is regarded to [this](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/issues/4303) issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK found the answer. There are a weird chars in the config file. VS Code and Notebook don't showed me the chars. After testing a couple online YAML validators, I detected the issue.

**[Youtube Video of the Error](https://youtu.be/TngMltxom5E)**

Comment: In my case it was tab instead of spaces...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use **keymetrics/pm2** this way:

```
services:
  keymetrics/pm2:
  ...
```

And it led to an error, but I solved it like this:

```
services:
  pm2:
    image: keymetrics/pm2
```